# Box Shadow effect Just on Top Left and Top Right

Tags: css

i was trying to set div's shadow, to just top left and Top right but it is not working by just changing the degree of angel...

the fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/2nmgB/

what i got is

```
.box h3{
  text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.effect4
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect4:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}

<div class="box effect4">
<h3>Effect 4</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked my answer? should solve your question, if so please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you turn every value (positioning/box-shadow/rotation) to the opposite you get a result with the shadow at the top:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nmgB/2/

change

```
top: 80%;
bottom: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
transform: rotate(3deg);
```

to

```
top: 15px;
bottom: 80%;
box-shadow: 0 -15px 10px #777;
transform: rotate(-3deg);
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in comments you want it right AND **left**:

Just add a second pseudo-element (`::before`) and place it accordingly:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nmgB/4/

```
right: auto;
left: 10px;
transform: rotate(-3deg);
```

Rest is the same as the `::after`-element

Answer (score 0):

Just use negative pixel offset instead.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28GuC/)

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/vinoddalvi/828fZ/1/

```
.box h3{
  text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.effect4
{
    position: relative;
}
.effect4:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 20px;
    left: 2px;
    right: auto;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(85deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(85deg);
    transform: rotate(85deg);
}
.effect4:before
{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 20px;
    right: 2px;
    left: auto;
    height:50%;
    width: 30%;
    max-width:300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 -15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(95deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(95deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(95deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(95deg);
    transform: rotate(95deg);
}
<div class="box effect4">
<h3>Effect 4</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: @JunaidFarooq : Do you want to display it in the top left and right sides of the displayed DIV ?

Comment: Yess. Like  ----> |||||| <----- (||) this is div so i want it on right left but just on top..

Comment: [link](http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b503/darulehsan031/title-12-A_zps7ad01b2a.png) check link and shadows of boxes please

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: I have updated the code to display it on top right left .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and change class names accordingly

```
<div class="class_box_shadow">Your code here <div class="sh_top_left"></div><div class="sh_bottom_right"></div></div>
```

your css style

```
.class_box_shadow{
    width: 374px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 130px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 5px solid white;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.sh_top_left{
    width:150px; height: 80px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; top:0;
    z-index:-2;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: -20px -30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: -20px -30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -20px -30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -webkit-transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(45px,20px);
    transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(45px,20px);
    -moz-transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(45px,20px);
}
.sh_bottom_right{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    right: 0; bottom:0;
    width:150px; height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -moz-transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-45px,-15px);
    -webkit-transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-45px,-15px);
        transform:skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-45px,-15px);
}
```

you can visit this site to create your own custom drop shadows.
http://www.themeshock.com/css-drop-shadow/

Comment: To make it visible on IE as well use this line of code            border-collapse:separate;